# Как создать typescript type definition (d.ts) файл для typescript umd библиотеки

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Есть библиотека, написанная на typescript. https://github.com/dmitrykurmanov/surveyjs

Собирается при помощи gulp+webpack в umd бандл.

Нужно создать type definition бандл или просто корректное множество d.ts файлов. Чтобы была возможность использовать эту библиотеку в typescript проектах.

Хотелось бы чтобы библиотека добавлялась в typings/global и подключалась как-то так:

```
import * as Survey from 'surveyjs';
```

при этом всё, что будет доступно в Survey.* описано например тут:
https://github.com/dmitrykurmanov/surveyjs/blob/master/src/entries/ko.ts

Попытки собирать bundle при помощи: https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator и
https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle не увенчались успехом, если кто-то поможет с конфигурацией этих проектов,тоже буду рад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был получен тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155100/how-to-create-typescript-definition-file-d-ts-for-umd-library

Посоветовали использовать `declaration flag`. Я создам ещё два вопроса, более точных про создание **bundle.d.ts** И про **webpack-stream**

Comment: знакомый пейзаж у тебя на аватарке. ты не из Тулы случайно?